# sending http requests from SQL server

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, sqlclr

We have a system in which the data is replicated from an external 3rd party source (which I have no control over).
The only way of manipulating the source data is via a Web Service.

For each newly replicated  row  I have to update another table in the external DB by sending a web request.

I know that it can be achieved by simply writing an SQLCLR routine that'll send http request. 
My question is : is this the correct way to go about this from the architectural standpoint ? Isn't it considered as misuse of CLR integration ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say you have identified a great scenario for use of CLR.  Microsoft publishes a good overview of CLR vs TSQL and when to use one and not the other - *I've included link below*.

Since you are accessing resources outside of SQL Server through .Net technologies I think your approach gets a pretty clear vote for CLR.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131045(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, accessing web services via SQLCLR is proper use of SQLCLR capability.

The only thing you must mind are timeouts on the side of your DB. The web services aren't well known for quick responses.